# attempting to add values of a 2D list to see if they equal to a even number

Tags: python, list

I have a concept problem I am trying to work on.

The goal is to take a 2d list. In each sub list of the 2d list, sum  the values within. If all sublists in the 2d list equal to even numbers return True, else Return False.

the code below is what I have. my errors so far are included below the code.

```
 input = evenrow([[1, 3], [2, 4], [0, 6]]) 

def evenrow (lst):
    for row in lst:
        for unit in row:
            if sum(int(unit)) %2 == 0:
                return True
        return False
```

errors =

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    evenrow([[1, 3], [2, 4], [0, 6]])
  File "C:\Users\Christopher\Downloads\pratice.py", line 57, in evenrow
    if sum(int(unit)) %2 == 0:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def evenrow(lst):
  for row in lst:
    if sum(row) % 2 != 0: # If the sum of at least one sublist is not even
      return False        # then we return False.
  return True             # If we get to this line, then all the sums are even.
```

Comment: thank you @irrelephant a question though. wouldn't that add all the values in all the sublists together and then see if they are even, rather then checking each sublist to see if its even? i.e. [3,1] [4,3], [4,2] = 4 + 7 + 6 = 17 = False compared to  [3,1] = 4 even [4,3] = 7 not even, [4,2] = 6 even 2 even 1 not even therefor false

Comment: No, because you're summing each row individually in the loop `for row in lst`.